# Pasar de String IP a Uint

Tags: c++

No encuentro la forma de pasar mi variable **String ip = "192.168.1.145"** a **Uint**. Este es el código que me ofrece el game engine, no puedo utilizar un Bool en clientConnectToServer, es necesario que sea del tipo SockAddr.

He probado a introducir directamente la ip como un numero entero a través de un conversor online, pero no crea la conexion con el servidor que esta escuchando en la misma ip en el puerto 65534.

Adjunto el código sin algunos getters.

```
#define  FREPA(    a)  for(Int i=     0 ;   i< Elms(a); i++) // forward repeat all : 0 .. Elms(a)-1

typedef   PLATFORM(unsigned __int32, uint32_t)   U32,   UInt; // Unsigned Int (32-bit)                           0 .. 4 294 967 295   

struct SockAddr // Socket Address
{
   SockAddr& port   (Int     port); //set port
   SockAddr& ip4    (UInt    ip4 ); //set IPv4
   Bool      ip4Text(C Str8 &ip4 ); //set IPv4 in text format
   Bool      ip6Text(C Str8 &ip6 ); //set IPv6 in text format
   Bool      ipText (C Str8 &ip  ); //set IP   in text format

   // set
   SockAddr& clear       (                      ); // clear address to zero
   Bool      setFrom     (C Socket &socket      ); // set   address from socket
   SockAddr& setServer   (              Int port); // set   address to be used for creating a server
   SockAddr& setLocalFast(              Int port); // set   address to local host     (  fast "127.0.0.1"     IP will be used), this allows connections only within the same device
   SockAddr& setLocal    (              Int port); // set   address to local host     ( local                 IP will be used), this allows connections only within the same device and local network (connecting beyond local network depends if the local host is behind a router)
   Bool      setGlobal   (              Int port); // set   address to local host     (global/public/external IP will be used), this allows connections      within the same device,    local network and beyond (resolving global IP address requires connecting to external websites !!)
   SockAddr& setBroadcast(              Int port); // set   address to broadcast mode ("255.255.255.255"      IP will be used), this allows sending to all computers in local network, this is IPv4 only and does not support IPv6
   Bool      setHost     (C Str  &host, Int port); // set   address to host from its name, false on fail
   SockAddr& setIp4Port  (  UInt  ip4 , Int port); // set   address to direct IPv4 address                with specified port
   Bool      setIp4Port  (C Str8 &ip4 , Int port); // set   address to direct IPv4 address in text format with specified port, false on fail
   Bool      setIp6Port  (C Str8 &ip6 , Int port); // set   address to direct IPv6 address in text format with specified port, false on fail
   Bool      setIpPort   (C Str8 &ip  , Int port); // set   address to direct IP   address in text format with specified port, false on fail

   Bool setFtp (C Str &host) {return setHost(host, 21);}
   Bool setHttp(C Str &host) {return setHost(host, 80);}

   // conversions
   Str    asText(               )C; // get address as   text
   Bool fromText(C Str8 &ip_port) ; // set address from text, false on fail

   // io
   Bool save(File &f)C; // save address to   file, false on fail
   Bool load(File &f) ; // load address from file, false on fail

   SockAddr() {clear();}

private:
   UInt _data[7];
};
    
int main()
{
        Connection temp[16];
        FREPA(temp)temp[i].clientConnectToServer(SockAddr().setLocal(0xFFFF-i));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes pasar la IP a valor así:

```
unsigned ip(const std::string &cadena)
{
    std::stringstream datos(cadena);
    std::string componente;
    unsigned resultado = 0u;

    // Leer cada valor usando el '.' como separador
    for (unsigned i = 0u; std::getline(datos, componente, '.') && i != 4u; ++i)
    {
        // Pasar el valor de texto a número.
        unsigned valor;
        std::stringstream ss(componente);
        ss >> valor;

        // Concatenar el valor en la IP numérica.
        resultado |= (valor << (8u * (3u - i)));
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Esta solución me permite automatizar la conversión, pero igualmente la conexion no se crea con el servidor al utilizar Uint, en cambio sí que funciona cuando utilizo **.setLocal()**

Comment: Si tu problema no es pasar de string IP a uint si no otra cosa, no hagas que el título de tu pregunta sea "*Pasar de String IP a Uint*".